# Select en Angular 6 - tomar datos de un doc firestore y pasarlo a otro doc

Tags: html5, angular, html-select, google-cloud-firestore

estoy iniciando en Angular y Firebase y me encontre con una cuestión: 
Como puedo hacer para que un select envie el valor seleccionado por un lado y el id del valor hacia otro doc.  Basicamente tengo 2 documentos (tablas) de firestore,  en una tengo los productos y en otra los movimientos.  Lo que requiero hacer es enviar el id del producto que selecciono a un campo de la tabla movimientos y el nombre a otro campo.

Hasta ahora tengo este codigo pero no funciona

Codigo en el html: (listaprod es la lista que viene del controlador)

```html
<select class="form-control col-sm-6" id="nomProd" [(ngModel)]="entradaTemp.nomProd" name="nomProd">
   <option *ngFor="let prod of listaprod | async">
      {{prod.nombre}} 
      <span name="idProd" id="idProd" [(ngModel)]="entradaTemp.idProd">{{prod.id}}</span>
   </option>
</select>
```

Cuando saco el span todo funciona correctamente me permite seleccionar, me muestra la seleccion y lo graba en el registro de entradas,  pero lo que no puedo es grabar el nombre e id en el registro de entradas.

Comment: Hola Marcelo! Te doy la bienvenida a [es.so], por favor termina el [tour] para que puedas ganar tu primera medalla :D

Comment: Hola y muchas gracias por la bienvenida,  en realidad el titulo deberia decir Como obtengo de un select 2 datos, el id y el nombre del producto.   Ambos datos se encuentran en el option pero no puedo lograr separarlos en por ejemplo dos variables distintas.   Nuevamente muchas gracias y saludos cordiales.

Comment: Muchas gracias Sebastian Excelente solucion con los formularios reactivos, son muy potentes y la verdad conocia de su existencia pero no me habia documentado. Muchas gracias por el link y la solución.

Comment: @MarceloLavandeira si existe una respuesta que ayudo a solucionar el problema puedes marcarla como aceptada, revisa el [tour].

Answer (score 0):

El uso del ngModel no es necesario. Puedes encontrar muchas más ventajas al realizarlo con formularios reactivos.  Si quieres aprender más, aquí te dejo los docs oficiales:

https://angular.io/guide/forms

### Solución

1. Debes tener los datos en un array que vas a recorrer en el select.
2. Crea un formulario reactivo para el select.

   - El formulario reactivo contendrá dos controles, uno para el id y otro para el nombre
   - En la vista solo llamas el control id
   - Sería algo así 
     `<select formControlName="id"><option *ngFor="const item of data">....</option> </select>`
3. Escuchas los cambio de ese control `form.get('option').valueChanges.subscribe((value) => { 
   // cambias el valor del control name
   // Filtras el valor del id para encontrar el nombre
   const itemFilter = data.filter((item) => item.id === value)
   this.form.get('name').setValue(itemFilter.name);
   }`

Answer (score 0):

Puedes darle `[ngValue]="prod"` de esa forma, el valor sera el objeto completo y podras obtener los valores que tu necesites del objeto.